# Solving $\int\sqrt{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{x+a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)}-\ln(x+a)-\frac{x}{b}+c} \, dx$ or $\int\sqrt{\ln(x+a)-\frac{x}{b}+c} \, dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms, radicals, rational-functions

So I've been investigating the movement of an object and managed to derive an equation of the following form which I have to integrate. However, I'm really not sure if this integral is even possible since it has so many different aspects to it:
$$\int\sqrt{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{x+a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)}-\ln(x+a)-\frac{x}{b}+c} \, dx$$
I honestly am stuck and have no idea where to start, if it is even possible at all.

---

If that can't be done, I was wondering if this integration is possible, or is there a way in which I can solve it:
$$\int\sqrt{\ln(x+a)-\frac{x}{b}+c} \, dx$$

Comment: I wouldn't use the word _complex_ to describe this integral, since it could cause confusion, and make someone think it involves the complex plane in some way. Perhaps something like _complicated_ or _difficult_? I'll leave that up to you. Or alternatively, just put the integral in the title.

Comment: "Solving" is the wrong word here. One solves problems; one solves equations. On evaluates expressions.

Comment: Instead of being nitpicky about language, maybe you could actually help the guy.